# Pandas - rolling average is giving a NaN column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of numbers:

```
df
        close
0       3247.50
1       3247.00
2       3247.25
3       3248.50
4       3249.25

#dtype: float64
```

When I try:

```
df['testma'] = df['close'].rolling(window=2, min_periods=(2)).mean()  # considering full session
```

The output is a `NaN` column. I can't think of any reason why this is happening. The code works on other dataframes.

Any ideas on what I can try?

Comment: works as shown with data provided for me. you try pandas-ta or some other technical indicator library that has built in

Comment: Check dtype of the close column?  Needs to be numeric not an object/string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `min_periods` to 1

```
df['testma'] = df['close'].rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).mean()  
df
     close    testma
0  3247.50  3247.500
1  3247.00  3247.250
2  3247.25  3247.125
3  3248.50  3247.875
4  3249.25  3248.875
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Just trying to figure out what the issue is with using the `min_periods=2`. This works on some other dataframes I work with.

Answer (score 0):

Tried running the code myself, and it seems like the expected result is occurring (i.e. NaN on the first cell because there aren't 2 values to calculate a mean from).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'close': [3247.50, 3247.00, 3247.25, 3248.50, 3249.25]})
df['testma'] = df['close'].rolling(window=2, min_periods=(2)).mean()

df.head()
```

|  | close | testma |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3247.50 | NaN |
| 1 | 3247.00 | 3247.250 |
| 2 | 3247.25 | 3247.125 |
| 3 | 3248.50 | 3247.875 |
| 4 | 3249.25 | 3248.875 |

If the issue is just that the first value is NaN, then that would be solved with the min_periods parameter.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'close': [3247.50, 3247.00, 3247.25, 3248.50, 3249.25]})
df['testma'] = df['close'].rolling(window=2, min_periods=(1)).mean()

df.head()
```

|  | close | testma |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3247.50 | 3247.500 |
| 1 | 3247.00 | 3247.250 |
| 2 | 3247.25 | 3247.125 |
| 3 | 3248.50 | 3247.875 |
| 4 | 3249.25 | 3248.875 |